# Nuance of using 仕事しなかったら or 仕事しなければ in this simple sentence?

Tags: nuances, subjunctive

I want to say "**It would be a waste if I do not have a job that does not make use of my Japanese (ability).**"

However, I've no idea which of these options sounds native or what the nuance of each option might be

(1) 日本語を生かす仕事しなかったら、もったいないよ。
(2) 日本語を生かす仕事しなければ、もったいないよ。

Comment: I don’t want to confuse you further but you might consider this third option, too: (3) 日本語を生かす仕事しないと、もったいないよ。

Comment: @aguijonazo That grammar doesn't come naturally to me, but "I understand it if I hear it." However, if THAT is what a native says, please write that as the answer. Then, I need to "re-reset" my subjunctive mood settings, because I never speak like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you ended the sentence and the fact that you omitted を after 仕事 suggest that this is part of an informal conversation. しなければ sounds a bit too formal in it, although it is perfectly fine in a more formal, especially written sentence.

> 日本語を生かす仕事をしなければ、もったいないと思います。

しなかったら is OK in casual speech, but it could sound a bit dialectal and certainly looks informal in writing. Certain regional dialects tend to use たら more than れば. When I am speaking in Kansai-ben, I would probably say せんかったら (if not せんと).

When I am speaking the standard variant of Japanese, I would most likely use と.

> 日本語を生かす仕事しない**と**、もったいないよ。

You get many more search results for [しないともったいない](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) than for [しなければもったいない](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%91%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) or [しなかったらもったいない](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)